# Filter data frame based on condition within pairs

Tags: r

I want to filter the below data frame to keep only the pairs (Patient) that have larger value in "relapse" compared to "Base" in the Time column. Please see desired output.

```
        Acc    value   Patient  TT Time
1 GSM771434 4.183034 Patient_1 TT2 Base
2 GSM771435 5.907734 Patient_2 TT2 Base
3 GSM771436 3.787809 Patient_3 TT2 Base
4 GSM771437 3.811790 Patient_1 TT2 relapse
5 GSM771438 4.056306 Patient_2 TT2 relapse
6 GSM771439 4.893940 Patient_3 TT2 relapse
```

out:

```
        Acc    value   Patient  TT Time
3 GSM771436 3.787809 Patient_3 TT2 Base
6 GSM771439 4.893940 Patient_3 TT2 relapse
```

Comment: With `dplyr  df %>%
  group_by(Patient) %>%
  filter(value[Time == "relapse"] > value[Time == "Base"])`.

Answer (score 1):

tmfmnk solution with dplyr is correct.

Here is one with `base`:

```
idx <- sapply(unique(df$Patient), 
              function(x) with(df, value[Patient == x][1] < value[Patient == x][2]))

> idx
Patient_1 Patient_2 Patient_3 
    FALSE     FALSE      TRUE 

> df[idx,]
        Acc    value   Patient  TT    Time
3 GSM771436 3.787809 Patient_3 TT2    Base
6 GSM771439 4.893940 Patient_3 TT2 relapse
```

It has a nice interim result, so maybe you care for this solution.